# Error setting up eureka server in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, netflix-eureka

Following along a tutorial that sets up a eureka server. I follow all the steps but go to run it when it should work and it crashes with this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eurekaServerBootstrap'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerBootstrap' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eurekaServerBootstrap' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot Create new Replica Node :JerseyReplicationClient: http://localhost:8010/eureka/apps/: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.photoapp.photoappdiscoveryservice.PhotoappdiscoveryserviceApplication.main(PhotoappdiscoveryserviceApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerBootstrap' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eurekaServerBootstrap' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot Create new Replica Node :JerseyReplicationClient: http://localhost:8010/eureka/apps/: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot Create new Replica Node :JerseyReplicationClient: http://localhost:8010/eureka/apps/: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1780) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot Create new Replica Node :JerseyReplicationClient: http://localhost:8010/eureka/apps/: 
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes.start(PeerEurekaNodes.java:106) ~[eureka-core-1.10.7.jar:1.10.7]
    at com.netflix.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext.initialize(DefaultEurekaServerContext.java:67) ~[eureka-core-1.10.7.jar:1.10.7]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot Create new Replica Node :JerseyReplicationClient: http://localhost:8010/eureka/apps/: 
    at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.createReplicationClient(JerseyReplicationClient.java:170) ~[eureka-core-1.10.7.jar:1.10.7]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration$RefreshablePeerEurekaNodes.createPeerEurekaNode(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.java:286) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-3.0.0-20201115.174246-1802.jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes.updatePeerEurekaNodes(PeerEurekaNodes.java:189) ~[eureka-core-1.10.7.jar:1.10.7]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes.start(PeerEurekaNodes.java:87) ~[eureka-core-1.10.7.jar:1.10.7]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/client/apache4/config/DefaultApacheHttpClient4Config
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder.build(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:183) ~[eureka-client-1.10.7.jar:1.10.7]
    at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.createReplicationClient(JerseyReplicationClient.java:168) ~[eureka-core-1.10.7.jar:1.10.7]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.config.DefaultApacheHttpClient4Config
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 68 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I looked up possible solutions including purging maven cache and this did not work.

Here are my dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Main class:

```
package com.photoapp.photoappdiscoveryservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class PhotoappdiscoveryserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PhotoappdiscoveryserviceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8010

spring.application.name=discoveryservice

eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
```

Upon researching the only reason I can see is it may have been a error dependency, any help to figure this out would be great thanks!

Comment: I created a project from here https://start.spring.io/ matching with your dependencies and copied your application.properties. It worked well.

Comment: @Steephen thanks, but if it worked fine for you do you have any idea why it hasnt for me?

Comment: @Steephen I also just tried using the website and still got the same error - feeling its a fault with my maven?

Comment: please you can clear ```.m2``` repository and try again?

Comment: @ThangavelLoganathan I have finally solved it, I do not know how, but I decided to create a application.yml as an option and tried it that way. This works and I do not know why and it is still broken in application.properies

Comment: Sounds great, but it's strange that not worked with app.properties file.

Answer (score 9):

I am also following the same tutorial as you. I also faced the same issue with Eureka. There are 3 ways to solve it.

1. Use Mainong's solution by adding `eureka.instance.hostname=localhost` in application.properties.
2. & 3) In the same tutorial there is a part on troubleshooting this issue.

You can either add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

or remove eureka-client dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way I have found around this so far is to create an application.yml file and add the properties this way:

application.yml:

```
info:
  component: DiscoveryService

server:
  port: ${port:8010}


eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 15
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
```

I am not sure what the error is or how to solve it any other way than this

edit: I have finally found the solution it is getting rid of the client dependency in the pom.xml. For some reason you cannot have both in the project or you get the bean error.

Comment: it worked for me using the application.yml thanks, but still not working using application.properties even when getting rid of the client dependency in the pom.xml. I don't know why !!!

Comment: ah i get it i guess, i think he didn't like the : eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true in my application.properties

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue after changing version to `2.5.2`
To resolve this issue, I had to change `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka` in `application.properties` to `eureka.instance.hostname=localhost`

[FOR REFERENCE] The contents of my `application.properties` file

```
server.port=8010
spring.application.name=eureka-discovery-service
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
#eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone= http://localhost:8010/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=true
eureka.server.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty=0
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds= 15
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds= 5
```

Comment: yes your solution worked. I was facing the same issue. Resolved after adding the hostname part.

Answer (score 2):

Replicated this in my local and ran. Facing same issue

**Solution:**

Just remove these 2 props from application.properties

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

And add this property

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

It will work!

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:
Just add this property.

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I added the dependency below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency
```

it worked for me. tks for help